# Random generator from vector with probability distribution in C++

Tags: c++, random, generator, distribution, probability

I have same problem as here [Distributed probability random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956486/distributed-probability-random-number-generator) but in c++. I know how to implement it but my question is - Is that functionaly build in current version of c++?

Comment: There ought to be something here for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution thats it! Why I haven't seen it for the first time? Ok, thanks. Your answer helped me.

Comment: And unfortunatelly Visual Studio doesnt support constructor with iterators. ( dist(someVector.begin(), someVector.end() ) :(

Comment: @user1483399 Does it support the constructor with an `initializer_list`? `dist({150, 40, 15, 3})`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ee462326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx . Maybe piecewise_constant_distribution could be used instead discrete_distribution.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, I'll answer the question.

This distribution can be produced using C++11's random number generation library. This first requires seeding a random number engine (here I use `std::mt19937`) and then using that engine with a `std::discrete_distribution` random number distribution.

`std::discrete_dstribution`'s constructor takes either an iterator range over a sequence of weights or an `initializer_list` of weights. The generated numbers are then weighted according to the corresponding index in the sequence of weights. That is, if `{10, 5, 1}` are the weights, `0` will be produced with `10/(10 + 5 + 1) = 0.625` probability, and so on.

The following code demonstrates a solution to the other question:

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 engine(device()); // Seed the random number engine
std::discrete_distribution<> dist({150, 40, 15, 3}); // Create the distribution

// Now generate values with:
std::cout << (dist(engine) + 1) << std::endl;
```