# How To Make Selection Random Based On Percentage

Tags: c#, math, random

I have a bunch of items than range in *size* from `1-10`.

I would like to make the size that the item is to be determined by the *percentage* or chance of the object being that size..

For example:

Items chance of being *size* `1` = `50%` *chance*

Items chance of being *size* `5` = `20%` *chance*

Items chance of being *size* `10` = `5%` *chance*

I know I would need to use a `Random` generator for this of course.

But just wondering how would some of you go about the logic of this in **C#**?

Comment: Why was this question closed as a duplicate of "how to generate a random integer"?

Comment: Fill a list with 50 ones, 20 fives and 5 tens (and others, until you have 100 items in the list). Then get a random number between 0 and 99 and use that as an index into the list to get the respective value.

Comment: No, OP is asking about how to get random numbers with a given distribution. Voting to repoen.

Comment: No the OP is asking how to make a proportional/roulette wheel selection, just like Corak answers (which should be an answer!).

Comment: Now this question, of course, has also been asked. Possible duplicate of [Distributed probability random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956486/distributed-probability-random-number-generator)

Comment: `50% + 20% + 5% = 75%` doesn't add up to `100%`, what is the complete set of possibilities?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all: the probabilities provided *don't add up to 100%*:

```
50% + 20% + 5% = 75%
```

So you have to *check* these values. You may want to *generate* these per cents:

```
// Simplest, but not thread safe
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

...
int perCent = s_Random.Next(0, 100);

if (perCent < 50)               //  0 .. 49
{
    // return Item of size 1
}
else if (perCent < 50 + 20)     // 50 .. 69
{
    // return Item of size 5
}
else if (perCent < 50 + 20 + 5) // 70 .. 74 
{
    // return Item of size 10
} 
...
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks alot. The other thing is that the number of items provided can range from 5-50. So is there a way to distribute weight amongst any number between 1-50. For example - Items #1 Max size is 50. So how can I make each size have a weight? because inside of 50 there is Size 10, size 2, size 20, etc. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 10):

Use my method. It is simple and easy-to-understand.
I don't count portion in range 0...1, i just use "Probabilityp Pool" (sounds cool, yeah?)
I make a list with all elements i want choose from. Every element has its own chance. It is useful to set the most common element chance = 100, so most rare elements would be 60 or 50.

[At circle diagram you can see weight of every element in pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYNCW.jpg)

[Here you can see an implementing of accumulative probability for roulette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crAUQ.jpg)

```
`

// Some c`lass or struct for represent items you want to roulette
public class Item
{
    public string name; // not only string, any type of data
    public int chance;  // chance of getting this Item
}

public class ProportionalWheelSelection
{
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    // Static method for using from anywhere. You can make its overload for accepting not only List, but arrays also: 
    // public static Item SelectItem (Item[] items)...
    public static Item SelectItem(List<Item> items)
    {
        // Calculate the summa of all portions.
        int poolSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            poolSize += items[i].chance;
        }

        // Get a random integer from 0 to PoolSize.
        int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, poolSize) + 1;

        // Detect the item, which corresponds to current random number.
        int accumulatedProbability = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            accumulatedProbability += items[i].chance;
            if (randomNumber <= accumulatedProbability)
                return items[i];
        }
        return null;    // this code will never come while you use this programm right :)
    }
}

// Example of using somewhere in your program:
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item() { name = "Anna", chance = 100});
            items.Add(new Item() { name = "Alex", chance = 125});
            items.Add(new Item() { name = "Dog", chance = 50});
            items.Add(new Item() { name = "Cat", chance = 35});

            Item newItem = ProportionalWheelSelection.SelectItem(items);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, maybe it will be useful for others.

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public int Percent { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChoiceItemModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Percent { get; set; }
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
    }

public int ChoiceProduct(List<Product> products)
        {
            var chioiceItems = new List<ChoiceItemModel>();

            var percent = 0;

            foreach (var product in products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Percent).ToList())
            {
                chioiceItems.Add(new ChoiceItemModel()
                {
                    Id = product.Id,
                    Percent = product.Percent,
                    Min = percent,
                    Max = product.Percent + percent
                });
                percent = product.Percent + percent; //max
            }

            var random = new Random();
            var probability = random.Next(1, 100);

            var found = chioiceItems.FirstOrDefault(p => probability > p.Min && probability <= p.Max);
            if (found != null)
                return found.Id;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I end using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267598/12197116) class of [Oleksandr Martysh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7437903/oleksandr-martysh), modified for generic types and specifically for Unity, in case someone see this usefull :)

```
public class ProportionalRandomSelector<T> {

    private readonly Dictionary<T, int> percentageItemsDict;

    public ProportionalRandomSelector() => percentageItemsDict = new();

    public void AddPercentageItem(T item, int percentage) => percentageItemsDict.Add(item, percentage);

    public T SelectItem() {
        
        // Calculate the summa of all portions.
        int poolSize = 0;
        foreach (int i in percentageItemsDict.Values) {
            poolSize += i;
        }

        // Get a random integer from 1 to PoolSize.
        int randomNumber = Random.Range(1, poolSize);

        // Detect the item, which corresponds to current random number.
        int accumulatedProbability = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, int> pair in percentageItemsDict) {
            accumulatedProbability += pair.Value;
            if (randomNumber <= accumulatedProbability)
                return pair.Key;
        }
        
        return default;  // this code will never come while you use this programm right :)
    
    }

}

//Example of use. You can use any type for the item too, and don't need an internal struct for the use.
public class Behaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    
    ProportionalRandomSelector<string> randomSelector = new();
    randomSelector.AddPercentageItem("Option1", 20);
    randomSelector.AddPercentageItem("Option2", 30);
    randomSelector.AddPercentageItem("Option3", 30);
    randomSelector.AddPercentageItem("Option4", 15);
    randomSelector.AddPercentageItem("Option5", 5);
    string result = randomSelector.SelectItem();
    
}
```